# Magento store email issue

Tags: email, magento

I have Magento website hosted on one server and my email server for the same domain hosted on other server.I am not receiving order mail confirmation on my domain mail id.Moreover i have set "Send Order Email Copy To" to my domain email id in magento store configuration. Furthermore my domain mail id is working fine in sending and receiving email.In addition to this when i add any gmail id to "Send Order Email Copy To" in admin panel. I am able to get order email confermation

Comment: Just check the other functionality like contact us or registration, if you got mails proper than it is related to order only, and emails work in queue by cron.

Comment: possible duplicate (and not the first!): http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41580/magento-website-not-sending-emails

Comment: sorry i am not able to receive any email like contact us or registration also.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your email server by using the following steps.

**Step 1** : Create a file (`testmail.php`) in your magento root directory

**Step 2** : Replace this the following code

```
<?php
require_once "app/Mage.php";
Mage::app(); 


// the message
$msg = "First line of text\nSecond line of text";

// send email
mail("someone@example.com","My subject",$msg);
?>
```

**Step 3**: Run the above code by http://yourdomainname.com/testmail.php

**Note** : see [PHP mail() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp)